# Add img to  ahref tag

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, image, href

I want the below format to be done from my codebehind:

```
<a href="">
<img src=""/>
</a>
```

I have done this way but I am not able to add image to `<a href>`
Can anyone say me how to do that?

Here is my code:

```
Dim urls As New List(Of String)
                urls.Add("Downloads/" & Session("tempDir").ToString & "/" & filename)
                For Each imageURL As String In urls
                    Dim img = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image()
                    img.ImageUrl = imageURL
                    img.Attributes.Add("src", "Downloads/" & Session("tempDir").ToString & "/" & filename)
                    img.Attributes.Add("rel", "group2")
                    img.Width = 75
                    img.Height = 50
                    img.CssClass = "clickImage"
                    img.ImageAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
                    Me.FinalPreview.Controls.Add(img)
                Next
```

I have found this:

```
Dim anchor As New HtmlGenericControl("a")
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#")
```

But I am not able to understand how do I add img to this If I add control the total img is not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `Literal` control

Place a literal control on the page and then add its text like this...

```
Dim strb as New StringBuilder()    
For Each imageURL As String In urls
   strb.Append("<a href='#'><img src='").Append(imageURL).Append("' /></a>");
Next
litImage.Text = strb.ToString()
```

Comment: @Naveed-Sorry for the late response.Thanks for your answer.And I have a small problem regarding this actually Literal control is a gud idea! but I have a div control where I need to add Images.And If I add this control to that div its shoin me that string cannot be converted to web.ui.controls.So how do I add this to my div.And as it is a text I can add one image instead of multiple.

Comment: I think you are trying to assign the string to Literal itself. Try to assign the string to Literal.Text

Comment: I got it! :)Thaks Once again.

Answer (score -2):

Image has a special property called ImageUrl to set the URL to.

Comment: @Vladimir-Thats's what I have done above but I need img to be added within the anchor tag.

Comment: `ImageUrl` is supposed to set the `src` of the image tag. it would not add an anchor control around the image tag...